# Can't figure out how to display seekbar value in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin

So I have a seekbar which I want the value of the seekbar to be displayed on the screen but android studio doesn't understand what the ID's I have described the seekbars and the texts are (the IDs are surrounded by stars)

All of the code that are surrounded by stars are in red and the interpreter doesn't understand. Any help on this?

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
private var textView: TextView? = null
private var progressBar: ProgressBar? = null
private var seekBar: SeekBar? = null
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.*activity_mq1*)
    textView = findViewById<View>(R.id.*textViewQ1*) as TextView
    progressBar = findViewById<View>(R.id.*progressBar*) as ProgressBar
    seekBar = findViewById<View>(R.id.*seekBarQ1*) as SeekBar
    seekBar!!.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(object : OnSeekBarChangeListener {
        override fun onProgressChanged(seekBar: SeekBar, progress: Int, fromUser: Boolean) {
            progressBar!!.progress = progress
            textView!!.text = "$progress%"
        }

        override fun onStartTrackingTouch(seekBar: SeekBar) {}
        override fun onStopTrackingTouch(seekBar: SeekBar) {}
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is your MainActivity in the same package you declared in manifest? Default resource package is the one declared in manifest.

E.g., if you have com.aaa as package in manifest, and your MainActivity is in com.bbb, you will have to import the resource package in MainActivity, something like

```
import com.aaa.R
```

Comment: Oh, well I am new to coding so please be patient with me but in all of my kotlin files, they all have the package imported